# Manually edit text in a Edge Animate animation directly in source code

Tags: javascript, html, adobe-edge, business-catalyst

My client wants me to translate his Web site from spanish to english, but it was originally made in Adobe Muse and hosted on Adobe Catalyst. I do have an account with Adobe Cloud, but the former designer doesn't want to allow us complete access to the site, just access to a limited admin console and to FTP.

So, I need to translate this Adobe Edge Animate:

http://bit.ly/1aQJCs2

There are 3 instances of text there that I don't know where to find for editing. I the following:

- edge_includes -> edge.1.5.0.min.js
- edge_includes -> jquery-1.7.1.min.js
- Experiencia1_edge.js
- Experiencia1_edgeActions.js
- Experiencia1_edgePreload.js
- Experiencia1.html
- images -> IMG_4064.jpg
- Poster.png
- telescopio.jpg

I look in all the files (except the image files of course) trying to locate the text:

Esperiencia
Innovación
Prestigio

And there isn't there. Is there a way to edit this text directly from the code? What am I missing here? I prefer not to install Adobe Edge Animate, but if I have to, can I use it to re-edit that animation with just the files I listed?

Thank you in advance,

Ed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this in one of my edge projects.  The text you wanna change is was probably just a text box created in Edge. What you want to do is open Experiencia1_edge.js.  Here is my example of something similar. If your designer labels things logically or organizes well you might see something with an id like Experiencia, Innovacion. It is important to look at the second line of the code block and it should say type: 'text'  This is a text element. Some will say type:'rect' or type 'image', but you want the one that says text.  In that block of javascript code like in my example you see text:"2014 Ford F-150 Raptor",  Just update the text in between the " " and save the file.  You should be all set after that

Code Before:

```
{     id:'fordraptortext',
      type:'text',
      rect:['-25px','37px','auto','auto','auto','auto'],
      text:"2014 FORD F-150 Raptor",
      font:['Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif',29,"rgba(208,201,192,1)","normal","none",""],
      transform:[[],[],[],['0.74','0.74']]
         },
```

Code After:

```
{     id:'fordraptortext',
      type:'text',
      rect:['-25px','37px','auto','auto','auto','auto'],
      text:"NOW MY TEXT WILL DISPLAY THIS",
      font:['Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif',29,"rgba(208,201,192,1)","normal","none",""],
      transform:[[],[],[],['0.74','0.74']]
         },
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That was the file that contained the variables. Best regards, Ed.